# Burninate the "multi" tag

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

[multi](/questions/tagged/multi). Used to signify multithreading, multi-domain, multimodule, multitouch, multiple keys, and multi-who-knows-what-else (often just general "more than one of anything"). In some of the cases, there are more appropriate tags which should be used (and which generally are being used in conjunction with it), and most of the rest of the time I think it's just not appropriate.

Comment: Most of those questions are going to have to be re-tagged by hand. They require the "human touch", if you will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]

Answer (score 5):

Ok. Retag requests abound.  @Cody's right, but I'd prefer not to bump 127 questions. So:

**I did the following by hand**

- <strike>[multi](/questions/tagged/multi) + [multithreading](/questions/tagged/multithreading) => [multithreading](/questions/tagged/multithreading)</strike> (15/127)
- <strike>[multi](/questions/tagged/multi) + [touch](/questions/tagged/touch) => [multitouch](/questions/tagged/multitouch)</strike> (6/127)
- <strike>[multi](/questions/tagged/multi) + [dimensional](/questions/tagged/dimensional) => [multidimensional](/questions/tagged/multidimensional) (3/127)</strike> <-- * Feel free to add more!

And how about a few synonym requests to go along with that?

- [multi-touch](/questions/tagged/multi-touch) (82 ?s) as a synonym of [multitouch](/questions/tagged/multitouch) (257 ?s)
- [multi-dimensional](/questions/tagged/multi-dimensional) (28 ?s) as a synonym of [multidimensional](/questions/tagged/multidimensional) (172 ?s)

as for the rest, I'm not sure if the remaining questions will really lose anything by dropping the [multi](/questions/tagged/multi).

**Update:** There are also some questions which should be [multiuser](/questions/tagged/multiuser).

Comment: Note that there is a `multidimensional-array` tag with over 1800 questions that might be better than just `multidimensional` when the question is about arrays.

Comment: Nice catch @hammar!

Comment: While on that subject, the [`dimensional`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dimensional) tag is fairly poor quality, and with only four tagged questions...

Comment: As far as I know, there's no automated way of retagging questions based on the presence of two tags, so that would make "bumping" somewhat inevitable. All we can do is create synonyms for a *single* tag. At least, moderators don't seem to have this ability; maybe devs do.